# When running fiddler Outlook stops working, how do I fix this?

Tags: https, outlook, fiddler

So at our office we have been having this problem where outlook will disconnect when you have fiddler up.  We have tried a few things but nothing has worked.  Any ideas?

And don't post a link to the google group that talks about this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/httpfiddler/j5ojJ0s6KGg
That doesn't work.  So any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tools->Fiddler Options->HTTPS
My coworker changed the combo box to ...from browsers only.  So far it seems to work, but this might end up not working.  So anybody with input would be appreciated.

Comment: That's the best workaround. This topic is covered in the Fiddler book at the end of Appendix A. The problem is that Outlook's RPC-over-HTTPS implementation isn't really valid HTTP traffic.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work when you need to monitor traffic that does NOT go through browsers...

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to me. Even in 2013 "every" browser had developer features like network monitoring. Fiddler is needed for everything else but browsers... I think there's a reason why this combo box doesn't exist (anymore).

Comment: Apparently whoever made fiddler did it in a weekend. The browsers have better dev tools now, and there are probably all sorts of extensions in vs code. Honestly, I haven't installed fiddler for over 4 or 5 years now.

Answer (score 15):

The best way I have found to solve it is to ue Fiddler (oh the irony) to see which hosts it requires to work (ie keep reconnecting and adding whatever hosts it connects to) until it no longer throws errors at simply keep them in the "Skip decryption" box. For me, on this computer, this works:

```
snt405-m.hotmail.com
hotmail.com
outlook.office365.com
```

Comment: This page can help to determine the name of the server used: http://www.uab.edu/it/home/component/k2/item/487-o365-activesync

Comment: Thanks for this, just what I needed!

Comment: I don't know what "ue Fiddler" means. Explain?

Comment: @Vincent hey that link is dead, looks like it is just a 404 now

Comment: Where is this '"Skip decryption" box'? Should you fill it if you don't capture HTTPS?

Comment: @TheincredibleJan THe "Skip decryption" box is accessed from the Fiddler menu by Tools > Options > HTTPS when "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" is enabled.

Answer (score 10):

I came across this as the first hit when I had this problem. I am using Outlook for Office 365 and skipping decryption for the hosts that Outlook connected to didn't work for me - Outlook was stuck trying to connect.
What worked for me was to add the following entries to "Bypass Fiddler for URLs that start with:" under Tools>Options>Connections:

```
*office.com; *office365.com; *live.com
```

Comment: Congrats on your first contribution. Have an extra upvote.

Answer (score 7):

This list works for the most part since I cant use just filter to browsers when developing API's.

Fiddler -> Tools -> Options -> HTTPS -> Skip decryption

These should exclude both Teams / Outlook when on a development machine.
Just be wary if you require any of the domains in question.

```
*.microsoft.com;
*.msn.com;
*.outlook.com;
*.live.com;
*.office.com;
*.office.net;
*.office365.com;
*.skype.com;
```

Comment: Congrats on your first Answer. A few more and you will be in business.

Comment: When I develop APIs I don't need to connect by HTTPS to Fiddler. I let the client use HTTP to 8888 the my debug pc and let Fiddler forward it via HTTPS through custom rule...

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The others are coping mechanisms, this actually solves the problem.